# API for Database using R

Tags: r

I am trying to use a httpr and jsonlite to access a database with a list of IDs. I want the name and any synonyms attached to that list.  The list has a length of 93.

I'd like to use the detail response model posed on the site (API) and it looks like this:

```
DetailResponseModel{ uri    string example: substance/pt/50000 rn   string example: 50-00-0 name    string example: Formaldehyde image  string example: <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" color-interpolation="auto" color-rendering="auto" fill="black" fill-opacity="1" font-family="'Dialog'" font-size="12" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" height="23.28" image-rendering="auto" shape-rendering="auto" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="none" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" text-rendering="auto" viewBox="0 0 2578 776" width="77.34"> <!--Generated by the Batik Graphics2D SVG Generator--> <g> <g fill="white" stroke="white"> <rect height="776" stroke="none" width="2578" x="0" y="0" /> </g> <g stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="44" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" transform="translate(32866,32758)"> <line fill="none" x1="-31812" x2="-30763" y1="-32494" y2="-32494" /> <line fill="none" x1="-31812" x2="-30763" y1="-32352" y2="-32352" /> <text font-family="sans-serif" font-size="433.3333" stroke="none" x="-32762" xml:space="preserve" y="-32242">CH</text> <text font-family="sans-serif" font-size="313.3333" stroke="none" x="-32185" xml:space="preserve" y="-32153">2</text> <text font-family="sans-serif" font-size="433.3333" stroke="none" x="-30729" xml:space="preserve" y="-32242">O</text> </g> </g> </svg> inchi    string example: InChI=1S/CH2O/c1-2/h1H2 inchiKey    string example: WSFSSNUMVMOOMR-UHFFFAOYSA-N smile   string example: C=O canonicalSmile  string example: C=O molecularFormula    string example: CH2O molecularMass  string example: 30.03 experimentalProperties    {...} example: List [ OrderedMap { "name": "Boiling Point", "property": "-19.5 °C", "sourceNumber": 1 }, OrderedMap { "name": "Melting Point", "property": "-92 °C", "sourceNumber": 1 }, OrderedMap { "name": "Density", "property": "0.8 g/cm3", "sourceNumber": 1 } ] propertyCitations  {...} example: List [ OrderedMap { "docUri": "", "sourceNumber": 1, "source": "Hazardous Substances Data Bank data were obtained from the National Library of Medicine (US)" } ] synonyms   {...} example: List [ "Formaldehyde", "BFV", "Fannoform", "Formalin", "Formalith", "Formic aldehyde", "Formol", "Fyde", "Methanal", "Methyl aldehyde", "Methylene oxide", "Oxomethane", "Oxymethylene", "Superlysoform", "Lysoform", "Morbicid", "Paraform", "Methaldehyde", "Floguard 1015", "FM 282", "F-gen", "Fordor", "NSC 298885", "Formalin LM", "Optilyse", "Formalin Taisei", "Formaldehyde-12C", "FS 850A" ] replacedRns  {...} example: List [ "8005-38-7", "8006-07-3", "8013-13-6", "112068-71-0", "1053659-79-2", "1156543-56-4", "1158237-02-5", "1227476-28-9", "1357848-44-2", "1416946-65-0", "1609158-91-9", "2100305-91-5" ]
```

I was able to hit the database and test it, but I cannot get it to return any hits..here is my code where I am asking the db to return a hit on the column CAS in file q:

```
q <- cas 
resp <- GET("commonchemistry.cas.org/api/search") 
query <- list(cas$CAS) 
print(query) 
resp <- GET("commonchemistry.cas.org/api/detail", query=query)

http_error(resp)
```

For the return above, I get 'true'
And for the error, I get: All components of the query must be named.

The list that I created has only named components so I am a bit confused.  Should I force it from a df to a list?

What am I doing wrong?  This is completely new to me.  I tried making it query one thing and that worked, but when I am trying to bring in the list and have it return the name of the agent, synonyms, and class I am having challenges.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us the contents of `cas`, so it's not quite clear what you're going for.

Nevertheless, this:

```
library(httr)
resp <- GET("http://commonchemistry.cas.org/api/search/", query=list(q="aspirin"))
rn <- content(resp)$results[[1]]$rn
detail <- GET("http://commonchemistry.cas.org/api/detail/", query=list(cas_rn=rn)) 
content(detail)
```

returns details on "aspirin", just as an example.

The `query=...` argument to `GET(...)` has to be a named list, so the first GET is equivalent to:

```
http://commonchemistry.cas.org/api/search/?q=aspirin
```

If you run this in a browser you'll see the structure of the json response, which shows why `content(resp)$results[[1]]$rn` contains the CAS registry number.

Comment: Hey!  The contents look like this: n CAS
1 100-51-6
2 100-52-7
3 102-13-6
4 102-76-1
5 103-45-7

Comment: The length is 93.  the n is just 1-93, the CAS is coded numerically with dashes.  I want to look up that entire row.  I converted it to a JSON list.  Can I code http://commonchemistry.cas.org/api/search/?q=query  for a query list?

Comment: Type `str(cas)` and paste the output into your question.